# Converter Decimal fracionário para binário

Tags: c

Estou tentando converter um numero decimal fracionário para binário.

Vamos ao exemplo, representando, em binário, o número 0,625.

> 0,625 x 2 = 1,25 , logo a primeira casa fracionária é 1.

Resta representar o 0,25 que restou ao se retirar o 1 já representado.

> 0,25 x 2 = 0,5 , logo a segunda casa é 0.

Falta representar o 0,5 .

> 0,5 x 2 = 1 , logo a terceira casa é 1.
>
> 0,62510 = 0,1012

Por enquanto eu fiz apenas para numero inteiro..

O código abaixo converte inteiro para binário.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Função Main
int main() {
 int n;
 int r;
 int i;

 // Lê o número
 printf("Digite o numero: ");
 scanf("%d", &n);

 // Utiliza um número de 32 bits como base para a conversão.
 for(i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Executa a operação shift right até a
    // última posição da direita para cada bit.
    r = n >> i;

    // Por meio do "e" lógico ele compara se o valor
    // na posição mais à direita é 1 ou 0
    // e imprime na tela até reproduzir o número binário.
    if(r & 1) {
        printf("1");
    } else {
        printf("0");
    }
 }

 printf("\n");

 system("pause");
}
```

como eu trato a parte fracionaria  em C?

Comment: Binário em que formato? Me parece que o que deseja é absurdamente mais complexo do que isto.

Comment: quero converter um numero DECIMAL PARA BINARIO .. no caso 0,625

Comment: Isto não diz nada novo.

Comment: No caso qualquer numero DECIMAL  fracionário para um numero binário , não sei explicar em outras palavras.  sei mostrar com numeros... 20,25 em binário é  (10100,01)

Comment: Binário não tem vírgula, você quer inventar isso?

Comment: Vc quer converter um float para binário é isso?

Comment: Em binário os dígitos possíveis são `0` e `1`. O `2` não faz parte. A representação `0.1012` não é uma representação válida dum número em binário.

Comment: Como o computador ja faz essa conversao internamente quando usas variaveis de tipo `double`, podes usar o trabalho do computador e apenas [interpretar os bits do formato IEEE](https://ideone.com/sm2s2k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O algoritmo que você quer pode ser criado a partir da seguinte lógica:

1. Dado um número `d` decimal, por exemplo `12.25d`;
2. Pegue a parte inteira do número e transforme em um número binário `b`: `12d` vira `1100b`;
3. Adicione o ponto ao número binário: `1100b` vira `1100.b`;
4. Remova a parte inteira do número decimal `d`: `12.25d` vira `.25d`;
5. Enquanto o número decimal restante for diferente de `0`, multiplique ele por `2` e adicione a parte inteira (que vai ser `1` ou `0`) ao seu número binário `b`:

`.25d * 2 = 0.50d` --> o `0` de `0.50` vai para o número binário `b` --> `1100.0b`. E o número decimal perde o `0` --> `.50d`. Repetindo o processo você tem que:

```
.50d * 2 = 1.0
```

tirando o `1` e adicionando ao número binário, seu resultado final é

```
12.25d = 1100.01b
```

---

Uma função simplificada que implemente a lógica acima pode ser definida em C da seguinte forma:

```
void fracaoParaBinario(double fracao) {
    fracao = fracao - (int)fracao; // removendo a parte inteira: 12.25d --> 0.25d

    while (fracao != 0.0) {
        fracao *= 2;
        int resto = (int)fracao;
        fracao -= resto;

        printf("%d", resto);
    }
}
```

E o código completo, o qual pode ser visto executando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/GVfE96):

```
# include <stdio.h>

void decimalParaBinario(int decimal) {
    char aux[1000000];
    int i, indice = 0;

    // simples conversão de decimal para binário:
    // divida o decimal por 2 enquanto ele for maior que 0,
    // sempre acumulando o resto das divisões, que compõem o número binário final.
    while (decimal > 0) {
        int resto = decimal % 2;
        aux[indice++] = resto + '0';

        decimal /= 2;
    }

    // o número binário em aux[] está invertido: 12d -->     0011b.
    // abaixo ele será consertado: 12d --> 0011b --> 1100b.
    for (i = 0; indice > 0; indice--, i++) {
        printf("%c", aux[indice - 1]);
    }
}

void fracaoParaBinario(double fracao) {
    fracao = fracao - (int)fracao; // removendo a parte inteira: 12.25d --> 0.25d

    while (fracao != 0.0) {
        fracao *= 2;
        int resto = (int)fracao;
        fracao -= resto;

        printf("%d", resto);
    }
}

void decimalComFracaoParaBinario(double numero) {
    decimalParaBinario((int)numero);
    printf(".");
    fracaoParaBinario(numero);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    double numero;

    numero = 12.25;
    decimalComFracaoParaBinario(numero);

    numero = 62.62510;
    decimalComFracaoParaBinario(numero);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: vou tentar algo.. assim que  eu conseguir eu posto também o resultado , caso alguém queira

Answer (score 2):

> como eu trato a parte fracionaria em C?

Como demonstraste no exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char output[100] = "";
    double x = 0.625;
    while (x) {
        int ch;
        double chk = x * 2;
        if (chk < 1) ch = '0'; else ch = '1';
        sprintf(output, "%s%c", output, ch);
        x = chk;
        if (x >= 1) x -= 1;
    }
    printf("Representacao final: 0.%s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Podes ver a [funcionar no ideone](https://ideone.com/jaOLTH).

Comment: sim curti isso , mas tem que tratar todos os casos possíveis. exemplo 20,25  também

Answer (score -1):

**Método simples para converter de binário para decimal na calculadora**

> PASSO 1: Defina quantos bits deseja obter na parte fracionária (F).
>
> PASSO 2: Multiplique o número fracionário por 2^F.
>
> PASSO 3: Use a conversão de decimal para binário da calculadora. Os
> bits mostrados são o resultado da conversão, com um deslocamento de F
> bits para a direita. Ou seja o ponto decimal está após o digito F (da
> direita para a esquerda). Faltando dígitos complete com zeros.

**Método simples para converter de decimal para binário na calculadora**

> PASSO 1: Escreva o número binário na calculadora (sem o ponto
> decimal).
>
> PASSO 2: Use a conversão de binário para decimal da calculadora.
>
> PASSO 3: Divida o resultado por 2^F, onde F é o número de bits da
> parte fracionária do número.

[Referência](https://wiki.sj.ifsc.edu.br/wiki/index.php/Convers%C3%A3o_de_decimal_para_bin%C3%A1rio_de_n%C3%BAmeros_fracion%C3%A1rios)

Comment: Entendo a boa intenção mas não vejo aonde isso ajudaria ele a fazer o cálculo em C, talvez no máximo o ajude a fazer uma prova real.